# How to perform an update containing a sub query on an Eloquent Relationship in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I'm working on this laravel 5 app but got stuck on trying to perform a query like below.

```
update applications 
set application_status = 'sa'
where id in (select application_id from application_cart where cart_id = 12);
```

Appreciate help on how to translate this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below does the trick

```
return Application::whereIn('id', function($query) use ($id){
            $query->from('application_cart')
                ->select('application_id')->where('cart_id', $id);
        })->update(['application_status' => 'sa']);
```